# PHP installed but Nginx not displaying it on the browser (possible conflict with WP Local by Flywheel)

Tags: php, nginx, local, flywheel

I have been recently working with WP Local (a.k.a Local by Flywheel) and all the PHP content of local Worpress sites work fine when they are started from inside this app.

Now I started studying PHP, unrelated to Wordpress, so **I have to do excercises outside of WP Local**. However, NGINX is not running my php code in the browser from pages stored at /var/www/html. It only displays correctly the html pages. PHP inside html pages doesn't work either.

Linux, nginx, php7 and mysql are installed (were installed by WP Local)

I would appreciate some light to make php code work (outside of the mentioned app).

Comment: Are you trying to run PHP without LocalByFlywheel?
On Local you can select NGINX or Apache

Comment: I am trying to do php excercises completely outside of Local.

Comment: So in that case you are not running any built-in server like Local.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.